# Duda productor-consumidor

Tags: java, hilos

Tengo un ejercicio en el que se me pide que el productor lea caracteres de un fichero y el consumidor los vaya leyendo e imprimiendo por pantalla. Para ello creé 3 clases (productor, consumidor y monitor) y la clase para probarla. La clase productor va leyendo los caracteres del fichero y se los pasa al monitor a través del método producir(). La clase consumidor llama al método consumir() de la clase monitor y lo imprime por consola.
La duda que tengo es la siguiente: según la clase monitor que adjunto, el método producir() va metiendo los caracteres leídos en el array buffer y cuando está llena el consumidor a través del método consumir, los va consumiendo e imprimiendo por pantalla. Pues bien, lo que no entiendo es por qué, según la implementación de los métodos, se imprimen los caracteres en el orden correcto y no al "revés", ya que según entiendo el método consumir empieza consumiendo la posición del array[4] y va descendiendo al disminuir la variable siguiente.

Edito: Adjunto las clases restantes. Aclaro que el código que proporciono me da la salida esperada, lo que no entiendo es por qué imprime por pantalla el texto del fichero correctamente y no a la "inversa" al recorrer el array donde se almacenan los caracteres del final al principio.

````
```

    package productorconsumidor2;
    
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    
    
    public class Monitor {
        private char[] buffer;
        private int siguiente;
        private boolean estaVacia;
        private boolean estaLlena;
        
        public Monitor(){
            this.buffer = new char[5];
            this.siguiente = 0;
            this.estaVacia = true;
            this.estaLlena = false;
                    
        }
        
        public synchronized char consumir(){
            while(this.estaVacia){
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Monitor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
            
            this.estaLlena = false;
            siguiente--;
            if(siguiente == 0){
                this.estaVacia = true;
            }
            
            notifyAll();
            
            return this.buffer[siguiente];
            
        }
        
        public synchronized void producir(char c){
            while(this.estaLlena){
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Monitor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
            buffer[siguiente] = c;
            siguiente++;
            this.estaVacia = false;
            if(siguiente == this.buffer.length){
                this.estaLlena = true;
            }
            notifyAll();
        }
    }




package productorconsumidor2;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class Consumidor extends Thread{
    Monitor monitor;
    
    public Consumidor(Monitor monitor){
        this.monitor = monitor;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            char letraConsumir = this.monitor.consumir();
            System.out.print(letraConsumir);
            try {
                sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Consumidor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
    
}

package productorconsumidor2;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Productor extends Thread {

    String fichero;
    static int caracterNumerico = 0;
   
   
    private Monitor monitor;
    
    Productor(String fichero,Monitor monitor) {
        this.fichero = fichero;
        this.monitor = monitor;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        FileReader fr = null;
        try {
            File fichero = new File("Fichero.txt");
            fr = new FileReader(fichero);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(fr);
            
            while (caracterNumerico != -1) {

                caracterNumerico = in.read();
                char letra = (char)caracterNumerico;
                monitor.producir(letra);
                
                sleep(1);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Productor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Productor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Productor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                fr.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Productor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        
        
    }


}


package productorconsumidor2;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class NewMain {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Monitor m = new Monitor();
        
        Productor p = new Productor("Fichero.txt",m);
        Consumidor c = new Consumidor(m);
        p.start();
        c.start();

    }
    
}


    

```
````

Comment: Maestro, dado que no proporcionas las otras clases, he probado creando un **main** con este código: **producir( 'W' );
        producir( 'a' );
       producir( 't' );
        producir( 't' );  for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
          System.out.println( consumir() );
       }** que imprime **"t", "t", "a", "W", osea que el problema está en las clases que no muestras.

Comment: Gracias por tomarte la molestia en leerlo. He adjuntado las clases restantes.

Comment: Para el formato de código, no debés agregar triples comillas ('''), sino triples acentos graves (```).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que no era problema...
Tus clases están bien, funcionan como se espera, el "problema es que se están ejecutando los dos hilos "muy" en paralelo, lo que hace que **productor**  cargue una letra en **buffer** y **consumidor** la descargue, por lo que siempre verás las letras en orden.
Una forma de verificar esto es cambiar el lugar de inicialización de **consumidor**, ejemplo:

```
 public synchronized void producir( char c ) { 

      // eliminé el "this"
   while( estaLlena ) {
      try {
         wait();
      }
      catch( InterruptedException ex ) {
         Logger.getLogger( Monitor.class.getName() ).log( Level.SEVERE, null, ex );
      }
   }
   buffer[ siguiente ] = c;
   siguiente++;

      // eliminé el "this" 
   estaVacia = false;
   if( siguiente == buffer.length ) {

         // eliminé el "this"
      estaLlena = true;

         // instancio "Consumidor" y le doy "mecha"
      Consumidor con = new Consumidor(  this );       
      con.start(); 
   }
   notifyAll();
}
```

Como puedes ver, instancio la clase una vez que **buffer** está lleno, y me muestra el orden esperado (por supuesto tengo que quitar del **main** de **newMain**, la inicialización).
PD: haces un uso redundante de "this", si no hay conflicto de nombres, y no debo pasar el objeto como parámetro, puedo omitirlo, por ejemplo:

```
public Monitor( ) {
   buffer = new char[ 5 ];
   siguiente = 0;
   estaVacia = true;
   estaLlena = false;
}
```

funciona perfectamente.

Agrego como debe quedar el **main**:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
   Monitor m = new Monitor();
   Productor p = new Productor( "Fichero.txt", m );
   p.start();
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tus aportes y comentarios del código pero sigo sin verlo. Al instanciar el Consumidor después de que el buffer esté lleno tendría en el buffer los siguientes caracteres: {'E','s','t','o','s'}. Al llamar a consumir(), la variable siguiente = 4, con lo que consumiría e imprimiría el carácter 's', y sin embargo imprime E, luego s, t..  eso es lo que no entiendo. Gracias

Comment: Sí, las he quitado. Y sigue saliendome por pantalla el texto correctamente. Tal cual lo extrae el fichero

Comment: El texto del fichero es el siguiente: Esto es un ejemplo de como se pueden usar los hilos en un problema típico Productor-Consumidor. Y la salida con tu main es:  eost sEun ejemplo
de como se pueden usar los hilos
en un problema típico Productor-consumido. Definitivamente no entiendo la lógica de la salida por pantalla

Comment: Ahhh, si miras el método **run** de **Productor**, la linea ** while( caracterNumerico != -1 ) {** hace que ante la aparición de un espacio, te tome el resto del texto como un carácter, lo que deberías hacer, es crear un array de palabras y con eso entrar en el while, te devolvería las mismas en orden invertido.